# Labelling the position of entry in the vector

Tags: vector

I probably explain my question by illustrating an example. For example,

```
Let $e_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ be the standard basis
vector for n-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
```

By drawing a little line and writing `$i^{th}$`-entry, I want to give the position of the entry in that vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\here}[2]{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0](#2){#1}}}

\begin{document}

Let 
\[
e_i=(0,\ldots,0,\here{1}{fromhere},0,\ldots,0)
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[font=\scriptsize, below right=12pt of fromhere] (tohere) {$i^{th}$-entry};
\draw ([yshift=-4pt]fromhere.south) |- (tohere);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip\noindent%
be the standard basis
vector for n-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let 
\[
e_i=(0,\ldots,0,\here{1}{fromhere},0,\ldots,0)
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[font=\scriptsize, below right=12pt of fromhere] (tohere) {$i^{th}$-entry};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=-4pt]fromhere.south) |- (tohere);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip\noindent%
be the standard basis
vector for n-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let 
\[
e_i=(0,\ldots,0,\here{1}{fromhere},0,\ldots,0)
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[font=\scriptsize, below right=12pt of fromhere] (tohere) {$i^{th}$-entry};
\draw[Stealth-] ([yshift=-4pt]fromhere.south) |- (tohere);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip\noindent%
be the standard basis
vector for n-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let 
\[
e_i=(0,\ldots,0,\here{1}{fromhere},0,\ldots,0)
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[font=\scriptsize, below right=12pt of fromhere] (tohere) {$i^{th}$-entry};
\draw[Latex-] ([yshift=-4pt]fromhere.south) |- (tohere);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip\noindent%
be the standard basis
vector for n-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to easily transform vertical line below 1 to a vertical arrow indicating 1?

Comment: @ToposLogos Of course, add `[<-]` to after `\draw`. If you want a different arrow tip, you can use `[Stealth-]` or `[Latex-]` (or many other options) loading `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty approach (in this case with labelling of two positions) in case you don't want to use tikz.

```
\[
\begin{matrix}
e_{ij} = &
        &(0,\ldots,0,&1,&0,\ldots,0,&1,&0,\dots,0)\\
        &&&\uparrow&     &\uparrow& \\
        &&&i&            &j& \\
\end{matrix}
\]
```

[image]